# CakePHP delete cascade do not work

Tags: cakephp

Excuse me my english...
I have two models: User and Note
In user.php:

```
var $hasMany=array('Note'=>array('className'=>'Note',
                                 'foreignKey'=>'user_id',
                                 'dependent'=>'true',
                                 'exclusive'=>'true'
                                 )
                    );
```

In users_controller.php:

```
function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for User', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete($id,true)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

But when I delete an user, the notes associated with the user are not eliminated!!!

What is wrong????

Comment: This code looks fine. Both your association and your `delete()` method call look perfect to process cascading deletion of associated data.

Answer (score 6):

It should be:

```
// In your User Model
var $hasMany=array('Note'=>array('className'=>'Note',
                                 'foreignKey'=>'user_id',
                                 'dependent'=>true, // true without single quote
                                 'exclusive'=>true
                                )
                );

//In your Note Model
var $belongsTo = array('User'=>array('className'=>'User',
                                     'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                             )
                );
```

And try now. It will delete the associated data also. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Thanks! The mistake was 'dependent'=>'true',
It must be 'dependent'=>true   whithout single quote as Arun Jain said!